# How to create almost sorted array of 100 with integers from 1-1000?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Part of my assignment requires 3 array of input size 100 with integers from 1-1000. Where 1st array is of random numbers from 1-1000. 2nd is sorted array from integers 1-1000. 3rd is almost sorted array from integers 1-1000.

My random array..

```
  int array [] = new int [100];    // Random Array of 100 
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < array-1 ; i++) {
      array [i] = (int) (Math.random () * 100);
     }
```

My sorted array..

```
  int [] array = new int[100];                    // Sorted Array of 100
    for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
      array[a] = (a + 1) * 10;
    }
```

But how to do a almost sorted array. I thought about shuffling but that will just be all random.

Comment: I would be surprised if your proposed solution for sorted array were to be accepted.

Comment: what is "almost sorted" array ?

Comment: Whats wrong with it? Requirement is array of 100 with integers 1-1000 so i did that.

Comment: There's no technical definition for an "almost sorted" array. As far as I can tell, just take the sorted array and swap two values and you're done.

Comment: almost sorted as in you start with half a random array and half sort array?

Comment: She didn't said anything. I guess anything works which is close to being sorted I tried swapping like every tenth integer couldn't get it to work

Comment: Create a sorted array of 100 integers. Now swap 2-3 random pairs. Doesn't it make a sorted array? Pseudocode: N=100; iter = 3; CreateSorted(arr, N); for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i) arr[rand()%N].swap(arr[rand()%N]);

Answer (score 0):

A faster solution:

```
int [] array = new int[100];    // Almost sorted Array of 100

array[0] = (int)(Math.random () * 10) + 1;

for (int a = 1; a < array.length; a++) {
  array[a] = array[a-1] + (int)(Math.random() * 12) - 2;
}
```

Hope that's close enough to an "almost sorted" array.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
        int[] values = new int[100];
        Random random = new Random();
        random.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            values[i] = random.nextInt(900) + 100;
        }

        Arrays.sort(values);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(values[i]);
        }
```

Comment: looks fine to me, but what it does can you tell me a little. spinning my head